# surface pro 3 as development device

Tags: windows-8.1

Is it possible to use the surface pro 3 as a dev test device.  I tried looking around and there wasn't much information.  What I mean by this is you connect your pro 3 to PC and deploy app to the tablet.  My guesses are that you cannot but I thought I would get some clarification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible you have to install remote debugging companents on your Surface Pro 3. And the appropriate one should be [x64 version of VS Update 3](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=43724) for you.

After you have installed the Remote Tools, choose Remote Debugger on the Start screen. The Remote Debugging Configuration appears the first time that you start the remote debugger.

On the Remote Debugging Configuration dialog box:

1. If the Windows Web Services API is not installed, choose Install
2. In the Configure Windows Firewall group, choose the networks that you want to allow connections to. Only those networks that the device is currently connected to are enabled. You must choose at least one network.
3. Choose Configure remote debugging to set the firewall options and start the remote debugger. Open the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor dialog box to give users permissions to the remote tools and to set other advanced options.
4. The Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor dialog box appears. You can give users permissions to the remote tools and set other advanced option from this dialog box. Here you can find information you need.

Choosing the remote device for C# and VB Project:

1. Select the project name in Solution Explorer and then choose Properties from the shortcut menu.
2. Select Debug.
3. Choose Remote Machine from the Target Device list.
4. Enter the network name of the remote device in the Remote Machine box or choose Find to choose the device from the Select Remote Debugger Connection dialog box.

You start, stop, and navigate a remote debug session the same way you do a local session. Before you start debugging, make sure the Remote Debugging Monitor is running on the remote device.

Then choose Start Debugging on the Debug menu (Keyboard: F5). The project is recompiled, then deployed to and started on the remote device. The debugger suspends execution at breakpoints, and you can step into, over, and out of your code. Choose Stop Debugging to end your debug session and close the remote app.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441469.aspx