# Remote debugging on Surface Pro 3

Tags: remote-debugging, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10, sideloading

I've installed **x64** version of [remote debugging components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh441469%28v=vs.120%29.aspx#BKMK_Installing_the_Remote_Tools) for **Visual Studio 2015** on my **Surface Pro 3** with Intel Core i3 CPU and recently updated to **Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview x64**.

When I'm trying to debug remotely simple universal application from Visual Studio 2015 RC (development machine runs Windows 8.1 Pro) I'm having this error in the output window:

> Error: Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named '192.168.1.2:4020 (hosthame)'.  The remote debugger is older than this version of Visual Studio 2015 RC, and Visual Studio is no longer compatible with it. Please upgrade your remote debugger to match Visual Studio.

Also there are records of failed attempt to connect in the main (log) window of Remote Debugging Monitor.

So, is there any "more updated" version of remove debugger component for Visual Studio 2015 RC then the current one I'm using, which, btw, has version **14.0.22310.1** and was "built by: DP" (have no idea what does it mean)?

Or any thoughts about other ways to workaround this issue?

I'm looking into installing Visual Studio on the Surface directly, but would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856229/surface-pro-3-as-development-device

Comment: @garenyondem, well, not exactly - this one was about issues debugging universal apps for Windows 10 with VS2015 remotely, not about "if it even possible or not".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I'll google next time harder - <strike>[Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2015 RC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46874)</strike> (this link is no longer available, please use the links bellow).

**Update (2016-06-28)**

Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2015 **Update 3**:

<strike>[Download](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-remote-tools)</strike> (this link is no longer available, please use the links bellow)

**Update (2016-09-28)**

- x64 - [Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615470&clcid=0x409)
- x86 - [Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615469&clcid=0x409)
- ARM - [Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2015](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=717854&clcid=0x409)

Comment: First link is broken, the second one helped me, thanks

Comment: I don't see anything useful about this error in the "Run Windows Store..." link above. Has the page changed since it was posted? I was actually followed the steps on that page and then got this error.

Comment: @Stephen the page was outdated so I've removed it. Please try updated links.

Comment: Do you know where the installer for ARM devices are?

Comment: @AH. I've updated download link - you'll need the **rtools_setup_arm.exe** installation package.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sevenate. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sevenate, your latest link is for the 2013 and not the 2015. Your second link still works, people just have to go to:
Tools for Visual Studio 2015->Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2015 and download the one for Update 3. I hope this helps
[image]

Comment: Thanks for noticed it -  I've updated answer with direct links.

Comment: Sevente, You still have 2013 in the link name. Haven't tested if they link actually points to the correct files though.

Comment: Thanks again, I've updated link text (though they pointing to 2015 version already).